# How to insert only month and year from vf page input

Tags: visualforce

I am using the below tag to display only month and year for user input.

```
  <input type="month" value="{!acc.lastissue}" styleClass="twitterStyleTextbox"/>
```

When i am trying to insert `acc.lastissue`value into a date field i am getting null value. Can anybody tell where it is going wrong.

Regards

Comment: Whats the datatype of acc.lastissue?

Comment: lastissue is date datatype..

Comment: can you add your complete code here? How are you submitting the form to backend?

Comment: i cant put the entire code as it too long..i have a save button where i insert lastissue variable to date field of an object..

Comment: I am more curious about how you are passing this date field back to SF? Is this snippet inside apex:form tag?

Comment: You can post the relevant code to save the date field only.